# Difference between "data" and "params" in Python requests?

Tags: python, python-requests

I was curious what the difference was between the `data` parameter and the `params` parameter in a `python-requests` request, and when each should be used.

One example is I have an array of dicts `users=[{"email_hash": "fh7834uifre8houi3f"}, ... ]` and I try to do a POST (`requests.post()`) with

```
params = {
    "ads_token": blah blah,
    "user_id": blah blah,
    "users": json.dumps(users)  # users=[{"email_hash": "fh7834uifre8houi3f"}, ... ]
    "hash_type": "md5"
}
```

and because `users` is a few hundred long, the resulting string from `json.dumps(users)` (and thus the URL itself as well) is very long and I get the error `{'status_code': 414, 'reason': 'Request-URI Too Large'}`. Would this be a case for `data` or is there some other path I should follow? Thanks!

Answer (score 77, accepted):

`params` form the [*query string*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) in the URL, `data` is used to fill the *body* of a request (together with `files`). `GET` and `HEAD` requests have no body.

For the *majority* of servers accepting a `POST` request, the data is expected to be passed in as the request *body*.

You need to consult the documentation for the specific API you are calling as to what they expect, but if you have to assume, assume you have to use `data`.

Comment: Awesome, thank you for the quick and concise answer! So the main difference is query string vs. body? And does that mean GET usually uses `params`, POST usually uses `data` (and `files`), and what about `DELETE`?

Comment: @tscizzle: the point of using a body is to allow for large amounts of  data to be transferred; it is rare a `DELETE` needs to transfer large amounts to get the method actioned on a server. Note that `data` and `params` are not mutually exclusive; I've seen URLs that accept POST requests with both query parameters *and* a body carrying meaning.