# Posting form data with requests and python

Tags: python, python-requests

Posting form data isn't working and since my other post about this wasn't working, I figured I would try to ask the question again so maybe I can get another perspective. I am currently trying to get the `requests.get(url, data=q)` to work. When I print, I am getting a page not found. I have resorted just to set variables and join them to the entire URL to make it work but I really want to learn this aspect about `requests`. Where am I making the mistake? I am using the HTML tag attributes `name=search_terms` and `name=geo_location_terms` for the form.

```
search_terms = "Bars"
location = "New Orleans, LA"
url = "https://www.yellowpages.com"
q = {'search_terms': search_terms, 'geo_locations_terms': location}
page = requests.get(url, data=q)
print(page.url)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have few little mistakes in your code:

1. Check form's *action* parameter. Then `url = "https://www.yellowpages.com/search"`
2. Second parameter is `geo_location_terms` not `geo_locations_terms`.
3. You should pass query parameters in `requests.get` as `params` not as request data (`data`).

So, the final version of code:

```
import requests

search_terms = "Bars"
location = "New Orleans, LA"
url = "https://www.yellowpages.com/search"
q = {'search_terms': search_terms, 'geo_location_terms': location}
page = requests.get(url, params=q)
print(page.url)
```

Result:

```
https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=Bars&geo_location_terms=New+Orleans%2C+LA
```

Comment: So when using `requests.get()` use ‘params’ and when `requests.post()` use `data` to pass the values?

Comment: @Kamikaze_goldfish not really, but usually it's so. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24535920/difference-between-data-and-params-in-python-requests).

Answer (score 1):

Besides the issues pointed by @Lev Zakharov, you need to set the cookies in your request, like this:

```
import requests

search_terms = "Bars"
location = "New Orleans, LA"
url = "https://www.yellowpages.com/search"

with requests.Session() as session:
    session.headers.update({
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.186 Safari/537.36',
        'Cookie': 'cookies'
    })

    q = {'search_terms': search_terms, 'geo_locations_terms': location}
    response = session.get(url, params=q)

    print(response.url)
    print(response.status_code)
```

**Output**

```
https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=Bars&geo_locations_terms=New+Orleans%2C+LA
200
```

To get the cookies you can see the requests using some Network listener for instance using Chrome Developer Tools Network tab, then replace the value `'cookies'`