# Sending a JSON Post using requests in python 3.7.2

Tags: python, json, http, get, python-requests

So im trying to use python to send a post to a url, i have basically copied everything from my network console in firefox yet i can't get it to work.

```
import requests
import json

url = 'https://www.example.com/example?handle'
cookie = {'UID':'b56f14d8-02b1-4ae8-ad5e-3485cf0abdbe'}
data ={'example':'example'}
headers = {'Accept':'*/*',
'Accept-Encoding':'gzip, deflate, br',
'Accept-Language':'en-US,en;q=0.5',
'Connection':'keep-alive',
'Content-Length':'78',
'Content-Type':'text/plain;charset=UTF-8',
'Cookie':'UID=b56f14d8-02b1-4ae8-ad5e-3485cf0abdbe',
'Host':'www.example.com',
'Referer':'https:/example.com/example',
'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:65.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/65.0'}


req = requests.post(url, cookies=cookie, params=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)

print(req)
```

I have replaced the actual data and url with example.
After running this, i get a big long error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Kaiser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32    \lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
chunked=chunked)
  File "C:\Users\Kaiser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 384, in _make_request
six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 2, in raise_from
  File "C:\Users\Kaiser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 380, in _make_request
httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "C:\Users\Kaiser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1321, in getresponse
response.begin()
  File "C:\Users\Kaiser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\http\client.py", line 296, in begin
version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "C:\Users\Kaiser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\http\client.py", line 257, in _read_status
line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
  File "C:\Users\Kaiser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\socket.py", line 589, in readinto
return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "C:\Users\Kaiser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 1052, in recv_into
return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
  File "C:\Users\Kaiser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 911, in read
return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Kaiser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 449, in send
timeout=timeout
  File "C:\Users\Kaiser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 638, in urlopen
_stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "C:\Users\Kaiser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 367, in increment
raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "C:\Users\Kaiser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 685, in reraise
raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Users\Kaiser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
chunked=chunked)
  File "C:\Users\Kaiser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 384, in _make_request
six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 2, in raise_from
  File "C:\Users\Kaiser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 380, in _make_request
httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "C:\Users\Kaiser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1321, in getresponse
response.begin()
  File "C:\Users\Kaiser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\http\client.py", line 296, in begin
version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "C:\Users\Kaiser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\http\client.py", line 257, in _read_status
line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
  File "C:\Users\Kaiser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\socket.py", line 589, in readinto
return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "C:\Users\Kaiser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 1052, in recv_into
return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
  File "C:\Users\Kaiser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 911, in read
return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Kaiser/Documents/python ddoser.py", line 19, in <module>
req = requests.post(url, cookies=cookie, params=json.dumps(data).encode('UTF-8'), headers=headers)
  File "C:\Users\Kaiser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 116, in post
return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Kaiser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 60, in request
return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Kaiser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 533, in request
resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Kaiser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 646, in send
r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Kaiser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 498, in send
raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.',     ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))
```

Does anyone know about what i could be doing wrong. Sorry if its a rookie mistake.

Comment: try commenting out 'Content-Length':'78'

Answer (score 3):

This error occurs when the web server rejects your connection. A web server can reject your connection for various reasons. Most likely, you did not properly mimic the HTTP request the web server was expecting.

You do not have to manually fill in all of the HTTP parameters such content length. The library automatically fills in these fields for you. If you plan to make subsequent HTTP requests using the same cookies, consider creating a session object, which stores and handles the cookies for you:

```py
session = requests.Session()
session.post(url, data=payload)
```

Also, realize the [difference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24535938/11168760) between the `data` parameter and the `params` parameter. Since you are sending a POST request, chances are that the web server is expecting the data to be passed via the `data` parameter (which places the data in the request body rather than the query string in the URL). Another reason a web server may reject your connection is because you sent a HTTP request rather than a HTTPS request, so always ensure everything is correct on your end.

Answer (score 0):

Below the code that i use to send post information and read the response,

```
import urllib2
from urllib2 import URLError, HTTPError 
import urllib
import ssl

    mydata=[('funcion',funcion),('codigo',codigo)]    #The first is the var name the second is the value

    headers = {"Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded","User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0",}

    handler=urllib2.HTTPHandler(debuglevel=1)
    opener = urllib2.build_opener(handler)
    urllib2.install_opener(opener)

    mydata=urllib.urlencode(mydata)
    path=url   #the url you want to POST to

    ctx = ssl.create_default_context() 
    ctx.check_hostname = False
    ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE    #In my case i need accept certificates


    req=urllib2.Request(path, mydata)

    req.add_header("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    req.add_header("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0")

    page=urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
```