# POST request remake from Java to python gets null

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, python-requests

I am totally new to python flask and encountered a problem when writing some code using the requests and flask modules.

I am working on a project using the web API offered by the Panther platform. The project provided an example using Apache Java.

The source code is as below ([see more](http://www.pantherdb.org/help/PANTHERhelp.jsp#V.E.) for details).

```java
public class TestProject {

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
    try {
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://pantherdb.org/webservices/garuda/tools/enrichment/VER_2/enrichment.jsp?");

        StringBody organism = new StringBody("Homo sapiens", ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN);
        FileBody fileData = new FileBody(new File("c:\\data_files\\gene_expression_files\\7_data\\humanEnsembl"), ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN);
        StringBody enrichmentType = new StringBody("process", ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN);       
        StringBody testType = new StringBody("FISHER", ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN);    
        //StringBody cor = new StringBody("FDR", ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN);
        //StringBody cor = new StringBody("BONFERRONI", ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN);
        //StringBody cor = new StringBody("NONE", ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN);
        StringBody type = new StringBody("enrichment", ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN);

        HttpEntity reqEntity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create()
                .addPart("organism", organism)
                .addPart("geneList", fileData)
                .addPart("enrichmentType", enrichmentType)
                .addPart("test_type", testType)
                .addPart("type", type)
                //.addPart("correction", cor)
                .build();
        httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);

        CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        try {
        //System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
       //System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
            HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
            if (resEntity != null) {
                System.out.println(IOUtils.toString(resEntity.getContent(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

            }
            EntityUtils.consume(resEntity);
        } finally {
            response.close();
        }
    } finally {
        httpclient.close();
    }
  }
}
```

The part I am mostly interested in is `.addPart("organism", organism)` and all the other code with similar structures. They will help pass the parameters from a third-party website to the web API offered by Panther.

I remade the JAVA code into `python3` using `requests`. The code is as follows:

```py
uploadTemp = {'file':open('./app/static/data_temp/temp.txt','rb')}

url="http://pantherdb.org/webservices/garuda/tools/enrichment/VER_2/enrichment.jsp?"
params = {"organism":organism,"geneList":pantherName,"enrichmentType":"fullGO_process","test_type":"BINOMIAL","type":"enrichment","correction":"BONFERRONI"}

# or params = {"organism":organism,"geneList":uploadTemp,"enrichmentType":"fullGO_process","test_type":"BINOMIAL","type":"enrichment","correction":"BONFERRONI"} 

Pantherpost= requests.post(url, params = params)
print(Pantherpost.text)
```

I am expecting an XML object from the web API including some basic biological information. However, the result I got was null (or `\n\n\rnull\n` when I print `Pantherpost.content`)

It seems that the parameters I have got from my own web were not correctly sent to the web API.

In addition to this getting null problem, as a beginner, I am also not quite sure about whether the "geneList" part should be receiving a plain-text object or a file. The manual says it is expecting a file, however, it may have been reformatted into plain-text by this command

```java
FileBody fileData = new FileBody(new File("c:\\data_files\\gene_expression_files\\7_data\\humanEnsembl"), ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN);
```

Anyway, I did try both interpretations: `pantherName` is a list with name correctly formatted in plain-text and `uploadTemp` is a .txt file generated for the project. There must be some extra bugs in my code since it returned `null` in both cases.

Can someone please help out? Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you remove all unnecessary commented lines and leave only correct paramters of the request? And please post example contents of .txt file.

Comment: And in your python example code `organism` and `pantherName` are undefined

Comment: `The manual says it is expecting a file` -> can you also give a link to that manual?

Comment: @Ivan Vinogradov Thanks for your comment. The url http://www.pantherdb.org/help/PANTHERhelp.jsp#V.E is the manual. It includes a description of the parameters. organism is a parameter passed from my web. Homo sapien, for example, is one among the others. I have it printed backend and it is correct. So it is with pantherName, which is a list of gene names. I will update a txt for test when I have access to computer. About the commented lines, indeed they show the two situations (txt upload and parameter) I am describing. So I am not sure whether I would like to remove them. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the following issues with your python code:

**One**. If you want to POST a file using `requests`, you should use keyword `files=`.

**Two**. Keys in `files` object should match respective parameters of the request (you're using `file` instead).

**Three**. You put your parameters in the wrong place of the request by writing `params=params`.

Function annotation from `requests` source code:

> :param `params`: (optional) Dictionary or bytes to be sent in the **query string** for the :class:`Request`.

In example Java code `StringBody` is used to create parameters, which implies that parameters should be placed inside the **body** of HTTP request, not query string. So [you should use](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests) `data=` keyword instead. If you use `params=`, output will be `null`.

[SO article on difference between](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24535920/difference-between-data-and-params-in-python-requests) `data` and `params` keywords in `requests`.

---

So I've spent some time reading thier manual and made a test script:

```py
import requests


url = "http://pantherdb.org/webservices/garuda/tools/enrichment/VER_2/enrichment.jsp?"
filepath = "C:\\data\\YOUR_DATA.txt"  # change to your file location

# all required parameters according to manual, except geneList which is a file (see below)
params = {  # using defaults from manual
    "type": "enrichment",
    "organism": "Homo sapiens",
    "enrichmentType": "process",
    "test_type": "FISHER",
    "correction": "FDR",
}

# note that the key here is the name of paramter: geneList
files = {'geneList': open(filepath, 'rb')}  

# it outputs null, when 'params=params' is used
r = requests.post(url, data=params, files=files)  
print(r.status_code)
print(r.text)
```

Output:

```
200
Id  Name    GeneId  raw P-value FDR
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I realized the data and params part earlier (but failed to update the post, sorry) and it still remained posting null. Your code works perfectly. I didn't realize it was expecting a file, not content of the file. It works perfectly now! Thanks.